# Python Sub Process with Tr Command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having trouble inserting a tr command into a subprocess.

I have the following:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('"tr < " + inputFile + " -d '\000' > " + nullFile', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but keep getting

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Can anyone see whats going on? It looks like it may be ' and " issues but not sure.

Comment: What do you expect `'"tr < " + inputFile + " -d '\000' > " + nullFile'` to actually evaluate to? Hint: single quotes don't nest like you seem to be expecting them to... Perhaps something more like `"tr -d '\\000' < {} > {}".format(inputFile, nullFile)` would be a better place to start...

Comment: should be: tr < file1 -d '\000' > file2

Comment: FYI, strings have a translate method. It would be easy to duplicate the tr functionality in pure Python.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way:

```
command = r"tr -d '\000' < {0:s} > {1:s}".format(inputFile, nullFile)
process = subprocess.Popen(command)
process.wait()
```

Comment: Just a somewhat redundant comment for python newcomers: _String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences_, see [2.4.1. String literals](//docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: `shell=True` is missing (`<>` redirection is a shell feature). Also, It fails if either `inputFile` or `nullFile` filenames have any shell meta-characters such as spaces in them. You could use `pipes.quote()` or better avoid `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `shell=True`, to call `tr` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

with open('input', 'rb', 0) as input_file, \
     open('output', 'wb', 0) as output_file:
    check_call(['tr', '-d', r'\000'], stdin=input_file, stdout=output_file)
```

Backslash is special inside Python string literals and therefore to pass the backslash, you either need to escape it: `'\\000'` or you should use a raw-string literal: `r'\000'`.

You don't need the external process here. You could remove zero bytes from a file using pure Python:

```
chunk_size = 1 << 15
with open('input', 'rb') as input_file, \
     open('output', 'wb') as output_file:
    while True:
        data = input_file.read(chunk_size)
        if not data: # EOF
            break
        output_file.write(data.replace(b'\0', b''))
```